# Handling Enter key of SIP in windows phone application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I want to know the best practice on handling the enter key . 
In code behind, ie, the .xaml.cs file, i can check for the e.key == Key.Enter way.

If i am following MVVM model, which is the appropriate method?

Making use behaviors is a good practice or not? Please suggest the professional way.
Since behavior is separate class from viewmodel class, i am little confused on how to go forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the event and the key-check in the code-behind for your UI logic, and then use a [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) , in MVVM known as the `Messenger` class, to dispatch the events to the view-model.

Comment: please provide some links which has samples using event aggregators.
I havent got much help in that .